# Deployed application will not post or get data

Tags: node.js

I have an angular app connected to a node.js server, deployed on A2 hosting service. This issue has been ongoing for weeks. The website is unable to post/get any data.

https://nathankeogh.com

Local node version: 14.15.4

Apache server node version: 14.18.3

The node.js application will always fail to start, due to some issue with the following code in server.js (22:5):

```
app.use('/accounts', import('./accounts/accounts.controller.js'))();
```

What is wrong that the apache server does not like this line of code?

Must I 'clean up' or refactor this the code in a specific way, to allow the server read it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to `POST` via your login form and checked the network logs, and got this interesting error message that wasn't displayed via your web app:

```
        <div class="left">
          <h3>Error ID:</h3>
          <span class="error">bb1f0ab8</span>
          <h3>Details:</h3>
          <p>Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger(R) application server.</p>
          <p class="bold">Please read <a href="https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/log_file/" class="plain">the Passenger log file</a> (search for the Error ID) to find the details of the error.</p>
          <p>You can also get a detailed report to appear directly on this page, but for security reasons it is only provided if Phusion Passenger(R) is run with <i>environment</i> set to <i>development</i> and/or with the <i>friendly error pages</i> option set to <i>on</i>.</p>
          <p>For more information about configuring environment and friendly error pages, see:</p>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_friendly_error_pages">Nginx integration mode</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerfriendlyerrorpages">Apache integration mode</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/#--friendly-error-pages---no-friendly-error-pages-friendly_error_pages">Standalone mode</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

More specifically:

> Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger(R) application server.

Looks like you have some config issues, not related to your codebase.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I contacted support and they are wiping their hands of the problem of course. Here's a look at the BS they are speaking https://imgur.com/a/y1iEiCD

Any idea of what type of configuration issue? Do you have any good guide for deploying full stack applications?